# Link not redirecting to other pages but works when directed to a division on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a navbar and the links are not working in it. When I go to the source code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>) and then click on the link, it redirects me properly.

Also when I remove the JavaScript, it works but doesn’t provide the required transition.

```js
(function() {
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.menu')).forEach(function(menu) {
    var menuItems = menu.querySelectorAll('.menu__link'),
      setCurrent = function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var item = ev.target.parentNode; // li

        // return if already current
        if (classie.has(item, 'menu__item--current')) {
          return false;
        }
        // remove current
        classie.remove(menu.querySelector('.menu__item--current'), 'menu__item--current');
        // set current
        classie.add(item, 'menu__item--current');
      };

    [].slice.call(menuItems).forEach(function(el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', setCurrent);
    });
  });

  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.link-copy')).forEach(function(link) {
    link.setAttribute('data-clipboard-text', location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '#' + link.parentNode.id);
    console.log(link);
    new Clipboard(link);
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
      classie.add(link, 'link-copy--animate');
      setTimeout(function() {
        classie.remove(link, 'link-copy--animate');
      }, 300);
    });
  });
})(window);
```

```html
<section class="section section--menu" id="Valentine">
  <nav class="menu menu--valentine" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; 
    right: 10px; width: 100%; float: right; background-color: black">
    <ul class="menu__list">
      <li class="menu__item menu__item--current"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="{% url 'speakers' %}" class="menu__link">Speakers</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="{% url 'partners' %}" class="menu__link">Partners</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#contact" class="menu__link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

What should I do? I’m pretty sure the error is due to the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `setCurrent` you are using `ev.preventDefault();`. The Default event, which you are preventing, is to go to the link.